# jQuery - cycle through multiple animations on single function / create array of animations so every animation is different and then it starts over

Tags: jquery, arrays, animation, fade, cycle

I need to have multiple animations cycling, or randomly changing, every time animation occurs on single function.

Currently there's a fade, what I want is to cycle through for example fade, toggle, animate, etc

Here is my code i need it to be used in:

```
var items = $(".items").on("click", "div", function() {
    var not = $.map($(".items div").not(this), function(el) {
      return $(el).index(".items div")
    });
    var next = not[Math.floor(Math.random() * not.length)];
    var index = $(this).index(".items div"); 
    var elems = $(">div", items).toArray();
    [elems[next], elems[index]] = [elems[index], elems[next]];
  $(this).add(items.find("div").eq(next)).fadeTo(600, 0, function() {
    items.html(elems).find("div").fadeTo(600, 1)
  });
});
```

I cant find any information about this anywhere but I saw it being used in some scripts, thanks a lot for ideas

Comment: Use an array of functions, that each does a different type of effect and returns a jQuery animation promise (e.g. `.promise()` on the jQuery objects). Then just run them sequentially/randomly (using `.then()` to run sequentially).

Comment: @Gone Coding can you maybe help me with specific code, that i can use in my case? Sadly, I'm not that good with jquery. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you can setup a JSFiddle example of your display/code I will see about a working example.

Comment: @Gone Coding here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/w8cmvu1m/

Comment: Almost there, but the overall aim of the logic is not obvious. What is the desired effect? To randomly transition with another random element and swap their values each time?

Comment: @Gone Coding ye, the code itself is fine as it is, to randomly swap between two elemets values, and the transition efect is just fade now, i want  to have multiple effects, for example first time its fade, than toggle than some custom animate, than toggle again, than fade etc... hope i am explaining it good enough. in short, having multiple random animation effects on that transition

Comment: Got it, just debugging a demonstration at the moment.

Comment: to give you bigger picture, im using this in grid gallery where is 15 images visible and other 30+ hidden, and that grid gallery is automaticly swapping images for different ones, and i need to have more than just one trasition efect there

Comment: Added a working example of what I was suggesting below. Note the html is not swapping for some reason in my example (head still fuzzy this morning) :)

Comment: @Gone Coding those effects are awesome! that way i can add basically any number of transition effects right ? thats exactly what i needed. If it would swap too, that would be perfect :D looking at it, i cant figure out why its not tho

Comment: You can add as many effects to the array as you like as it uses the array length for the random indexing of effect. I am also a little puzzled what I did wrong with the simple swap. Maybe I am swapping twice?

Comment: I think the fade/slide callback functions may be called back *once for each element*, so it is swapping twice. That was not what I expected, so will rethink that part :)

Comment: Not really happy with this, but it works (now swaps once per effect): https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w8cmvu1m/6/

Comment: I love you ! thanks a lot its awesome !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial version was simpler, but slightly bugged as the effect callbacks for the swap get called twice. New version at the bottom:

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w8cmvu1m/5/

The transitions are queued up in this example using `.then()`

```
$(function() {

  // Swap the html of two elements
  var swap = function($elements) {
    var val = $elements.eq(0).html();
    $elements.eq(0).html($elements.eq(1).html());
    $elements.eq(1).html(val);
  };

  // Array of effects functions - each takes 2 jQuery elements and swaps the values while not visible
  // Each returns a promise that resolves once the animation has completed
  var effects = [
    // fade in/out
    function($elements) {
      return $elements.fadeOut(function() {
        swap($elements);
      }).fadeIn().promise();
    },
    // Animate
    function($elements) {
      return $elements.slideUp(function() {
        swap($elements);
      }).slideDown().promise();
    }
  ];

  // Start with a resolved promise
  var promise = $.when();

  // Delegated handler for click on items
  $(document).on("click", ".items div", function() {
    // All items except this one
    var $item = $(this);
    var $notThis = $(".items div").not($item);

    // Randomly choose another item
    var $other = $notThis.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $notThis.length));

    // Randomly choose an effect
    var effect = Math.floor(Math.random() * effects.length);
    promise = promise.then(effects[effect]($item.add($other)));
  });
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var $items = $('.items div');
    $items.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $items.length)).click()
  }, 3000);
});
```

Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/w8cmvu1m/6/

I corrected the double-callback issue using deferreds and promises, but not happy with the solution:

```
  var effects = [
    // fade in/out
    function($elements) {
        var def = $.Deferred();
      $elements.fadeOut(500).promise().always(function() {
        swap($elements);
        $elements.fadeIn(500).promise().always(function(){
            def.resolve();
        });
      });
      return def.promise();
    },
    // Animate
    function($elements) {
        var def = $.Deferred();
      $elements.slideUp(500).promise().always(function() {
        swap($elements);
        $elements.slideDown(500).promise().always(function(){
            def.resolve();
        });
      });
      return def.promise();
    }
  ];
```